# ColdFusion Performance Implication of Query of Queries

Tags: coldfusion, qoq, fusionreactor

This is an extreme longshot, but once in a while there is an engineer on here that knows what's going on under the hood.

First, I know that you can almost always rewrite some code to avoid QoQ for much better performance. However, what I'm trying to debug is a potential reason that code that uses QoQ would perform so poorly under certain conditions to develop guidelines for future projects.

1) Is there something about the ColdFusion QoQ Java implementation that would cause access to the QoQ system to be single threaded? ([I saw post on Railo about this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/railo/Fsh-uuwE2ic/SetqhPXrbpYJ))

2) According to FusionReactor, the stack trace has the request *always* in the evaluate (90% chance) or execution phase (10% chance) of the QoQ -- never any other part of the logic surrounding it. That's with it running in a loop with a query param.

We have several different features that make use of QoQ in a loop over tens of thousands of iterations to generate a report, regardless of that being best practice or not. The *only* processes that slow down are the ones that use QoQ. They become 10 times as long to complete unless they are kicked off nearly immediately after a server reboot. FusionReactor always has the thread state at evaluating the QoQ or processing the QoQ. Of note: the Heap and CPU are just fine holding steady at under 20% during the entire duration. All memory spaces look good -- code cache, perm, etc.

I **know** that running QoQ in a loop is not the way to get it done and should be changed, but I'm just looking for answers. Is code locked? Is it an available thread issue? Is there something about evaluating the statement? Why would it be fine right after a restart, but quickly degrade within hours? That's what bugs me -- I'd be fine with it taking forever always, it's the oddball pattern that has me on stack overflow.

ColdFusion 10 if it helps.

Comment: I do not think it is a thread issue. QofQ runs in the request thread like other logic operations. Under the hood it is doing array/struct comparisons - usually of strings. One way to optimize is to sort your initial data effectively and make sure you are using the right data type in your QoQ to avoid implicit type conversions (like float to string for example). But if you think of a function to compare and extract an array of structs to antother array of structs - it's expensive unless it's very small data sets. sorry.

Comment: JT - post some code - maybe we can offer some specific suggestions.

Comment: @MarkAKruger I agree it is totally inefficient, especially in comparison to building a struct once which is far more efficient for repeated lookups. What I'm trying to understand is why this particular logic could slow down over time when other CPU bound logic does not. Code is a simple QoQ straight from the books. There is no datatype issue -- I've experienced that hell with dates before.

Comment: yes - beyond 300/400 rows its not great. sorry. Straight from the books is sometimes a problem though (ha).

Comment: FYI - I actually like and recommend it in some cases - readible and easy to conceptualize and below a certain threshold works with zero impact.

Comment: @MarkAKruger It has it's place for sure. But am more concerned about the degradation in performance over time. Usually you can attribute this behavior to memory or CPU, but this is seemingly not the case.